# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - while writing pdf to outputstream

Tags: java, outputstream

PDF gets downloaded for the first time, from next time it throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
. The current Max heap size is 536 MB

```
httpResp.setHeader("Expires", "0");
httpResp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
httpResp.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
httpResp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+"BulkIdCard"+".pdf");
httpResp.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
httpResp.getOutputStream().write(byte[]);//pdf in byte array
httpResp.getOutputStream().flush();
httpResp.getOutputStream().close();
```

Comment: How large are these PDF documents, and is some handle to the first document sticking around somewhere?

Comment: Your heap might be able to handle first byte[] created when first download happened and when you download it again, again it is creating another byte[] which is out of your assigned Java Heap capacity. Are you creating new byte[] every time you receive a download request?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen PDF size depends, it can be of 1 page or it can be 50 pages. for one tested flow the PDF size is 7 MB and the number of pages is 14.

Comment: @shyampatil yes every time the request comes, new byte [] is created.

Comment: if byte[] is the only heavy object, your downloading flow has, then i will recommend 're-using' java.nio.ByteBuffer object for byte array instead of raw byte[]. I mean using same ByteBuffer for every download request, making sure it is(ByteBuffer.clear()) cleared before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of luck the PDF is generated as byte array using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Rewriting to a method parametrized with an `OutputStream`, and passing `httpResp.getOutputStream()` should do.

It is however a good moment to check the produced PDF for redundant data. Appending does not remove data becoming obsolete, repeated images should be stored only once and so on. Comparing with a PDF optimizer or a clean write might give pointers. Less data, better response times, server loads.

Answer (score 0):

Because your heap maximum is times larger than your test document it is not very likely that the content delivery itself consumes that much memory.

Either the surrounding runtime infrastructure consumes that much memory (e.g. Application Server, ...) or you have some memory leak in there.

If you think the infrastructure is not the problem, try analyzing your heap content `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify upto half of your RAM size in the following commands.
For example, if you have 4GB RAM then specify size upto 2048M in the following commands.If 2048 is not working, then try with somewhat less size say 2000M etc...and so on.Please check this when you use in your IDE whether it is Netbeans or Eclipse etc... or increase your RAM size.

```
java -Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size 

(OR)

java -Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```